# centos yum repository package security information.. how do i find it?

Tags: centos, httpd, yum, documentation

Is there anywhere that shows which security updates are included in the patch levels for centos yum repository package version of httpd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you can check the changelog of the package (and check for lines containing CVE if it's a known vulnerability): `rpm -q --changelog httpd`
- you can also search for "http" or "apache" on Red Hat CVE web page: https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/